# How to call function in a veiw in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" height="100%" frameborder="0" align="top" src="index.php/home/slider"></iframe>
```

this is my view file of index but iframe is not working properly please tell me , which source can i give?

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {       $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->view('index');
    }

    function slider()
    {   
            $this->load->view('slider');      
    }
}?>
```

this is my home.php

Answer (score 0):

Home is your class name and first try to remove index.php using .htaccess and your url should be like this

```
src="<?php echo site_url('home/slider'); ?>"
```

removing index.php use this code in your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: when you use site_url, you no need to worry about the htaccess or index.php

Answer (score 0):

use [**site_url()**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) in source (src)

example :-

```
site_url('home/slider');
```